# How to convert a CSV (with quote) to TSV?

Tags: csv

https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers-1.csv

The following command won't convert the above file well.

```
$ csvformat -D $'\t' < protocol-numbers-1.csv
...
86  DGP Dissimilar Gateway Protocol     "[M/A-COM Government Systems, ""Dissimilar Gateway Protocol
Specification, Draft Version"", Contract no. CS901145,
November 16, 1987.][Mike_Little]"
...
```

The above lines shown should be in oneline. And the enclosing double quotes are not necessary. What is a robust way to convert such a CSV file with quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is

```
mlr --c2t --quote-none put -S 'for (k in $*) {$[k] = gsub($[k], "\n", " ");}' \
then clean-whitespace protocol-numbers-1.csv  >out.tsv
```

There is a global search and replace, to remove `\n`.

The output https://gist.github.com/aborruso/d14caf4fafcc298e04e94958bcabf6ab